# What are good beginner packages for object avoidance?

Tags: ros, packages, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm using ROS for a class project, but I'm very much a beginner, so I'm still getting adapted to the libraries and packages and all. I intend to use this package ...ros.org/wiki/cob_collision_velocity_filter?distro=groovy to use as the foundation for object avoidance; however, I'm unsure if that's a better start than building object avoidance from the ground up. The robot on which I'll use the code has a kinect, laptop camera, and proximity laser. I don't know how well the packages will match up. I'd like your suggestions on what I should try first so I won't have to invest too much time in a chicken egg or something over my head. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56387/what-are-good-beginner-packages-for-object-avoidance?/) by [chaosprodigy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4305/chaosprodigy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the standard navigation stack should do the trick.  (http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials).  I think it's difficult enough getting all of the navigation pieces working together, it's probably best not to re-invent the wheel, especially when you're just starting.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2